# Example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not $\sigma$-finite under Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know open and closed sets are $\sigma$-finite. What would be the example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not $\sigma$-finite under Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Song  If the subset is Lebesgue measurable, then it is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Song are you confusing $\sigma$-compact with $\sigma$ -finite?

Comment: @zhw For some reason, I've read $\sigma$-finite as $\sigma$-compact. Thanks for pointing out my error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to @zhw pointing out my mistake) If we allow $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ to be a non-measurable set, then obviously it cannot be a countable union of measurable sets of a finite measure. We can construct a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]^2$ in a similar way constructing a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). This can be an example of a non-$\sigma$-finite set that you are looking for. However, we cannot find any examples among measurable sets. The reason is as follows. Note that every measurable set $E$ can be expressed as
$$
E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n
$$ where $E_n =E\cap [-n,n]^2$ and that each $E_n$ has a finite measure $m(E_n)\le m([-n,n]^2)= 4n^2$. This shows that there are no measurable, non-$\sigma$-finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You deleted your comments that I corrected, didn't answer my question there, then provided an answer with zero acknowledgement. Not really a cool thing to do.

Comment: @zhw. I'm so sorry about that if it makes you feel bad. At first I did leave a comment appreciating your pointing out my mistake, but after a while I deleted it only because I thought you probably already read it. Again, I apologize for such a misbehavior.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comment here. In the future, at times, you might want to consider not deleting comments of yours even if they're mistaken. Often the resulting discussion can help readers.

Comment: @zhw Oh, I think it's a really good point. I'll keep it in my mind. Thank you!